# In android emulator Google Maps work fine but in real device it doesn't not a blue simple object of Maps is appearing

Tags: android, google-maps

I applied the exact steps as mentioned in the google developer doc to create an example google map project and everything went fine on the emulator, but in all real device google map doesn't show up not also simple map object only white screen saying google may service are updating.

In **gradle** dependency

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.0'
```

Emulator Google play service version 9.6.83(480-133155058)
Samusung j5 Google play service version 10.2.98(438-146496160)

I do have API key and entered in Manifest.

**I have tried in real device on google play service version 9.6.83(480-133155058) it works but not for version 10.2.98(438-146496160).**

In emulator the maps only works if dependency is 
`com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.6.0` or less than it.

```
<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:largeHeap="true"
android:theme="@style/Theme.Bbtechgroup">
<activity
    android:name=".ui.activity.MainActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="@string/google_maps_key"/>
```

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

defaultConfig {

    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 22

}

buildTypes {
    debug {
        debuggable true
    }
    release {
        debuggable false
        minifyEnabled false
        signingConfig signingConfigs.keys
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}



configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'gson', module: 'gson'
}


compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
```

}

dependencies {

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.6.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.6.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'
```

}

Comment: pls show you manifest, gradle and logs when you run on real device

Comment: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/11/google-play-services-and-firebase-for-android-will-support-api-level-14-at-minimum.html?hl=be

Comment: @xbadal Plzz go through of manifest and gradle

Comment: Anyone found solutions about this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem long time ago! i just change one thing and it worked for me. `<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="@string/google_maps_key"/>`

instead of referring to string file paste you key here. as

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
android:value="bcbcVCHYRKddd88ejj"/>
```

Try it out once.

Comment: try to clean and rebuilt you project

Answer (score 0):

> In emulator the maps only works if dependency is  com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.6.0 or less than it

The Android Studio emulators don't always have the latest Google Play API unless you explicitly update it yourself from an APK or getting the Play Store installed.

---

The most common reason for a blank map is that your API key isn't correct or some other service request / authentication request is denied in your code.

Comment: Yeah thanks,I know it will ask for update obviously but my main question was for real device but you r right we have to update it manually.
In real device at 9.6.0 i guess this should work bcoz it has version 10.2.98.

Comment: If it works on a lower version than on a newer version of the library, then there is some request service going wrong. I assume the API key wouldn't change between versions, so maybe it's permissions or something else

Comment: Yeah, in real device it always shows Google Play Services are updating on white screen.